# As a non-root user, how to install another version cuda in conda environment in Linux server?

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, conda, miniconda

I am a non-root user in a Linux server, when I input `nvidia-smi` it shows my cuda is 10.2.

However, my project is asked to
`pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Now, I have create my own environment, for example, cu111, by `conda create --name cu111 python=3.10` and `conda activate cu111`
What should I do step by step, the first step is following `pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` ,right?

I read some tutorial, it asked to add path variable in your environment, but I am not sure if it is correct,

```
export PATH=/home/dj/miniconda3/envs/cu111/lib/:$PATH
```

Any suggestion is helpful for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a non-root user in a Linux server, when I input nvidia-smi it shows my cuda is 10.2.

The "CUDA version" shown by `nvidia-smi` is the **maximum CUDA version supported by the GPU driver installed on the system**. That means that no matter what CUDA toolkit or CUDA accelerated framework you choose to install, nothing newer than CUDA 10.2 or anything compiled against anything newer than CUDA 10.2 will actually work on the machine in question. If you install a version of PyTorch compiled against CUDA 11.1, it cannot work on the machine in its current state.

If you are a non-root user, there is nothing you can do to fix this other than ask a system administrator to perform a driver upgrade (if that is possible, i.e. the hardware is actually supported by a more modern driver).

Comment: What about this situation: the cuda version is 11.1, can I install a cuda version 10.2 in my environment?

Comment: If you mean the driver has a support level of 11.1, that is a maximum, so yes earlier versions of the CUDA toolkit and frameworks built against earlier versions of the toolkit can work with that driver.